# Why "This" does act as a private member in a javascript function in this case?

Tags: javascript, debugging, this, private-members

I try to call a public member in a function, and it appears as 'undefined' however the function works...

**-- EDIT --**
As pointed out by @Shane Voisard `this` is acting as a member of the parent of my function.

Solution is to give a name to the function (as Shane underlined in answer).

... or to attach the function to a name :

```
MySite.Public.Logo = { 

        inject : function(target){

             this.name = 'Logo';
             ...
        }
}
```

In console  :

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.name; //return "Logo"
```

and so on... thx SO

**-- /EDIT --**

My file system is like this

```
root folder :
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 1921 avril  3 17:31 0.js
drwxr-xr-x  9 www-data www-data 4096 avril  3 17:37 public

public folder :
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  214 avril  3 17:37 0.js
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 avril  3 17:40 modules
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 avril  3 17:40 factories
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 avril  3 17:40 functions
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data 4096 avril  2 22:22 singleton

module folder : 
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  28 mars  31 06:07 1.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 348 avril  3 17:51 logo.js
```

Loading is made in this order :
`root/0.js` initializes `MySite = {}`
`public/0.js` initializes `MySite.Public = {}`
`module/1.js` initializes `MySite.Public.Modules = {}`

When all others needed files are loaded, `public/0.js` calls `MySite.Public.Modules.Logo()`, which has been initialized when `logo.js` has been loaded into the browser. The function works, I can get a return from logo.js. But none of the `this` members are publicly accessibles...

Content of `logo.js` :

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo = function(){

        this.name = 'Logo';

        this.build = function(){
                var logo = MySite.Public.Factories.HTML.make('logo');
                return logo;
        };  

        this.inject = function(target){
                var logo = this.build();
                var target = MySite.Public.Functions.ToolBox.getElementByName(target); //getElementByName is a custom function
                target.appendChild(logo);
        }; 

}
```

In the console :

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.inject('body'); // undefined is not a function...
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.build(); // undefined is not a function...
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.name; // ""
typeof MySite.Public.Modules.Logo; // "function"
```

Content of `logo.js` : *// to test the function I give target to the constructor*

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo = function(target){

        this.name = 'Logo';

        this.build = function(){
                var logo = MySite.Public.Factories.HTML.make('logo');
                return logo;
        };  

        this.inject = function(target){
                var logo = this.build();
                var target = MySite.Public.Functions.ToolBox.getElementByName(target);
                target.appendChild(logo);
        };  

        this.inject(target);

}
```

In the console :

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo('body'); //works
```

And still...

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.inject('body'); // undefined is not a function...
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.build(); // undefined is not a function...
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo.name; // ""
typeof MySite.Public.Modules.Logo; // "function"
```

Does someone has a clue, please, on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo()
MySite.Public.Modules.name // "Logo"
```

When you call Logo(), `this.name` refers to the `MySite.Public.Modules` object.  When you invoke a function in a object method context, javascript implicitly assigns the object to `this` inside the invoked function at runtime.

If you want the methods defined on your function object, give the function a name and then refer to the name inside the function:

```
MySite.Public.Modules.Logo = function init(target){

        init.l_name = 'Logo';
        init.getName = function { return l_name };

        init.build = function(){
                var logo = MySite.Public.Factories.HTML.make('logo');
                return logo;
        };  

        init.inject = function(target){
                var logo = init.build();
                var target = MySite.Public.Functions.ToolBox.getElementByName(target);
                target.appendChild(logo);
        };  

        init.inject(target);

}
```

**Edit**: The [`name` property of a function object *might* be read only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), depending upon the javascript environment.   Thus, you may need to use a different property name internally and expose a pretty accessor method.  For example, in Chrome developer tools, I could not assign to `init.name`.

`MySite` is your global object, but you refer to `Innov24` as if `Innov24 = MySite`.

I highly recommend [Javascript: The Good Parts by Douglas Crockford](http://amzn.com/0596517742).

Comment: yes, you are right ... but I cant figure out why. Thk you it leads me on the way. About the innov24/MySite, indeed MySite === innov24, but I tried to make ma question generic.